# Activating Sumproduct Array (C+S+E) deactivates when workbook re-opened

Tags: arrays, excel

I've been scratching my head for a few hours with a couple of very time consuming issues.
I have a sumproduct formula totalling the number of bookings within a month and a year, and another doing the same but totalling the profit instead of the number of bookings.

the formula for each is below:

```
Bookings
=SUMPRODUCT(--(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000<>""),--(MONTH(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000)=1),--(YEAR(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000)=2013))

Profit
=SUMPRODUCT(--IF(ISNUMBER(BAU!$AA$3:$AA$10000),BAU!$AA$3:$AA$10000),--(MONTH(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000)=1),--(YEAR(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000)=2013))
```

two issues I have, firstly, I have about 300 Cells I with such formulas, these cover clients for each month and each year, activating these with control shift enter takes a LONG time individually, When I attempt to activate all of them at once, the month and year criteria in the formulas e.g. (=1 & =2013) is duplicated across every cell, so instead of searching for each month, every cells only queries against =1 (january), can this be avoided?

Secondly, after manually control shift entering EVERY cell and saving/closing the workbook, the #VALUE error is in every cell when I reopen it, meaning I have to repear the whole CSE process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry if I've not made much sense, I tried my best to.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using excel 2010, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looks like this is what you want

```
=COUNTIFS(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,">=1/1/2013",BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,"<=1/31/2013")
```

And

```
=SUMIFS(BAU!$AA$3:$AA$10000,BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,">=1/1/2013",BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,"<=1/31/2013")
```

you do not need to enter these as arrays just as normal formulas.

If you need to Change the dates ever I would do something like the following:

In A1 (Or what ever cell you'd like to enter the date in) Right click the cell and click Format Cells..., Then under the "Number" Tab (usually the tab it will open too) click on Custom. Then enter "m/y" Where it says Type:.

From there you enter a month and a year into the cell.

Then modify the formulas to this

```
=COUNTIFS(BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,">="&A1,BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,"<="&A1+30)
```

And

```
=SUMIFS(BAU!$AA$3:$AA$10000,BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,">="&A1,BAU!$X$3:$X$10000,"<="&A1+30)
```

Replace A1 With the cell you choose to enter the date in. Enter the date as "1/13" for this example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, a combination of the above examples have solved my problem :)